# create anonymous object in php

Tags: php, class, object

```
include('Property.php');
$obj = new Property ();
$obj->price = 2500.00;
$obj ['address_primary'] = '100 Main St';
$obj->state = 'VA';
echo 'Address :: ', $obj->address_primary, ' ', PHP_EOL;
echo 'City, State, Zip :: ', $obj ['state'];
```

Can please someone Explain to me how, from having this : $obj = new Property ()  we can create/initialize or have : $obj ['address_primary'] and be able to echo this : $obj->address_primary

Sorry but I try to explain the problem as much as i could. Thanks for your answers Folks!!

Comment: does Property extend ArrayAccess? If not, you shouldn't be doing stuff like $obj['address_primary'], it will always be $obj->address_primary

Comment: Property class code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a property as an array element. You need to extend ArrayObject. http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php to do this. Otherwise dont mix objects and arrays.

Comment: By Extending the class 'Property' to ArrayObject(), it should take care of this as well, right? : `$obj->price = 2500.00;` `echo $obj ['state'];`

Comment: @Blingue no prob, dont forget you can vote up answers that helped! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just change

```
$obj ['address_primary'] = '100 Main St';
```

to

```
$obj->address_primary = '100 Main St';
```

You'll also have to change

```
echo 'City, State, Zip :: ', $obj ['state'];
```

to

```
echo 'City, State, Zip :: ', $obj->state;
```

Answer (score 0):

> File 'Property.php' 
>   Add property 
>   $address_primary = ""; 
>   $defaultAddress  = "This is temp address to test";
>   funciton __construct($primaryAddress = ""){ 
>      this->address_primary = (strlen(trim($primaryAddress)) > 0)?
>         $primaryAddress :$defaultAddress;
>       
>   }